# Build failure while trying to update to "org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.15.1"

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.15.1:generate (default) on project event-dao-jooq: Execution default of goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.15.1:generate failed: Unable to load the mojo 'generate' in the plugin 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.15.1' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/jooq/codegen/maven/Plugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Answer (score 4):

jOOQ 3.15 requires Java 11 (class file version 55) and you are using Java 8 (class file version 52) in your build. You either need to upgrade to Java 11, downgrade to jOOQ 3.14, or purchase a license for jOOQ 3.15 as all of the commercial editions still support Java 8.